# Using For loop and If condition in Django to display Images in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I haven been looking everywhere for a case similar to this, but haven't found anything that could solve my problem. I want to display an image from a model in my html inside a for loop, which has an if condition. This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class CarouselItem(models.Model):
    carousel_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='carousel_images/', null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import CarouselItem

# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    carousel_items = CarouselItem.objects.all()
    context = {
        'carousel_items': carousel_items
    }
    return render(request, "home/index.html", context=context)
```

and my html:

```
    {% if carousel_items %}
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  {% for item in carousel_items %}
      {% if forloop.first %}
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="{% item.carousel_picture.url %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      {% else %}
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="{% item.carousel_picture.url %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
{% else %}
    <h3>We are sorry, there are currently no Images to display</h3>
{% endif %}
```

When I want to access the page associated with the html I get this error message:

```
Invalid block tag on line 86: 'item.carousel_picture.url', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

I feel like I am making a mistake somewhere else, but I can't figure out what it is. I am using Bootstrap 4.5.3 and Django 3.1.5

All of the other html files in this project have no issues with displaying images using for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

`{% item.carousel_picture.url %}`

which is for templates logic, use:

`{{ item.carousel_picture.url }}`

which uses the value.